# Drupal 8 use suggested template when programmatically rendering node

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-nodes

I'm **rendering a node programmatically** from within a **Block** class in a **Drupal 8 module** and I would like to be able to use one of the **suggested template names** I get in the generated DOM to **override** how the node is rendered.

Unfortunately, any suggested name I use to create the template in my templates folder is **ignored** and Drupal renders the **basic bartik node.html.twig template**.

Here are the relevant parts of the code :

```
<?php

/**
  * @Block
  */


/**
  * {@inheritdoc}
  */
public function build()
{
    $events = [];
    $eventNodes = $this->repository->findBy(['status' => 1], [ 'field_date' => 'ASC' ]);
    $viewBuilder = $this->entityManager->getViewBuilder('node');
    foreach ($eventNodes as $eventNode) {
        $event = EventMapper::fromNodeToEvent($eventNode, [
            'title' => 'field_titre',
            'start' => 'field_date',
            'end'   => 'field_fin'
        ]);

        $build = $viewBuilder->view($eventNode, 'full');
        $event['html'] = $this->renderer->renderRoot($build);

        $events[] = $event;
    }

    $months = [];
    if (count($events) > 0) {
        $indexer = new EventIndexer($events);
        $months = $indexer
            ->indexByMonths()
            ->getResults()
        ;
    }

    return [
        '#theme' => 'calendar_block',
        '#events' => $events,
        '#attached' => [
            'library' => ['calendar/calendar'],
            'drupalSettings' => [ 'events' => $events, 'monthsIndex' => $months ]
        ]
    ];
}

/**
* Custom finder in a repository service. get list of nids and load
* them.
*/

/**
  * @param array $criteria
  * @param array $orderBy
  * @param int   $limit
  * @param int   $offset
  *
  * @return array<Node>
  */
public function findBy(array $criteria = [], array $orderBy = [], $limit = null, $offset = 0)
{
    $query = $this->queryFactory->get('node');
    $query->condition('type', self::TYPE);
    foreach ($criteria as $field => $value) {
        $query->condition($field, $value);
    }

    if (!empty($orderBy)) {
        foreach ($orderBy as $field => $direction) {
            $query->sort($field, $direction);
        }
    }

    if (!is_null($limit)) {
        $query->range($offset, $limit);
    }

    $nids = $query->execute();
    $events = $this->etm->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);

    return $events;
}

/**
  * Twig fragment where the rendered event is printed.
  *
  */

{% for event in events %}
    <div class="js-calendar-slider-event calendar-slider-event" data-start="{{events[loop.index0].start|date('Y-m-d') }}" data-end="{{events[loop.index0].end|date('Y-m-d') }}">{{ event.html }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a theme suggestions hook by hook_theme()

like i run a test case for you, i have write a hook_theme()

in my module file here is code

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $theme = array();
  $theme['node__contentTypeName'] = array(
    'render element' => 'content',
    'base hook' => 'node',
    'template' => 'node--contentTypeName',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/templates',
  );
  return $theme;
}
```

then place your template twig file in my_module/templates folder

here is my block code

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
/**
 * Provides a 'example node render block' Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "example_node_render_pulgin_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("example render node"),
 * )
 */
class ExampleNodeRenderBlock extends BlockBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    $nid = 36;
    $entity_type = 'node';
    $view_mode = 'full';
    $view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder($entity_type);
    $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type);
    $node = $storage->load($nid);
    $build = $view_builder->view($node, $view_mode);
    $output = render($build);

    return array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $output,
    );
  }
}
```

i have add some extra code in twig file to make sure my template is rendering or not

this is the line i have add in my template.twig

```
<div><h1>hello its me</h1></div>
```

and finally i place my block some where and here is result

[image]

Hope this solve your problem

Thanks